# Remove repeated parts of an list of strings

Tags: python, list

I have a list as below:

```
list = ['15206', '15207', '15269', '15370', '15220', '16224']
```

I need to remove the repeated parts of each value based on the first:

```
['15206', '07', '69', '370', '20', '6224']
```

Does anyone know how I can do this? I'm using Python.

This is the actual code:

```
lcod = ['15206', '15207', '15269', '15370', '15220', '16224']

poped = {} # this dict store the number of letters removed in each code

# Each iteration removes 1 letter
for i in range(10):

    for seq, cod in enumerate(lcod):
        poped[seq] = 0

        if seq >= 1:
            for seqLetter, letter in enumerate(cod):
                # the "seqLetter <= 3" means that it only can remove 3 letters of each code
                if letter == lcod[0][seqLetter-poped[seq]] and seqLetter <= 3:
                    lcod[seq] = cod[1:]
                    poped[seq] += 1

print(lcod)
```

returns `['15206', '5207', '5269', '370', '220', '224']`

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Are you stuck anywhere? What happens if there appears one string which is completely different from `'15206'` like  `'9734'` and then again it appears `'15207'`?

Comment: Why is the `'0'` not removed from `'15207'`?

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev edited with my actual code

Comment: @wjandrea I want to have a pattern, where the last two letters remain

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
list1 = ['15206', '15207', '15269', '15370', '15220', '16224']
list2 = []
for x in list1:
    count = 0
    value = ''
    for y in range(0,len(x)):
        if list1[0][y] == x[y]:
            if count == 1:
                value = value + x[y]
            elif y >= len(x)-2:
                value = value + x[y]
        else:
            value = value + x[y]
            count = 1
    list2.append(value)
list2[0] = list1[0]
print(list2)
```

Output :

```
['15206', '07', '69', '370', '20', '6224']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List = ['15206', '15207', '15269', '15370', '15220', '16224']

for i, x in enumerate(List.copy()[1:], start=1):
    num = 0
    for a, b in zip(List[0], x):
        if a == b:
            num += 1
        else:
            break
    if num >= 1:
        Run = True
        List[i] = List[i][num:]
print(List)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using set for this purpose. They might be faster as well, and easier to understand. I think it can be further concise.

```
lcod = ['15206', '15207', '15269', '15370', '15220', '16224']

patterns = {lcod[0][:i+1] for i in range(len(lcod[0]))}
new_patterns = []
for i, x in enumerate(lcod[1:]):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        if x[:j+1] not in patterns:
            new_patterns.append(x[j:])
            break
print(new_patterns)
```

Output:

```
['7', '69', '370', '20', '6224']
```

Edit:
Just now read that you want minimum last to characters to remain. Just add condition for that inside inner loop:

```
        if x[:j+1] not in patterns or j==len(x)-2:
            new_patterns.append(x[j:])
```

Output:

```
['07', '69', '370', '20', '6224']
```